# MySql in array order?

Tags: mysql

I have a statement like the below. The order returned is 1,4,5. My code expects 4,5,1 because of output precedence rules. How do i make mysql return the order i specified?

```
select *
from Post 
where flag='0' and id in(4,5,1)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
select *
from Post 
where flag='0' and id in(4,5,1)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '4,5,1')
```

MySQL Doc for [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: Nice! it seems to give it to me in the order 1 5 4 (writing this as a note to others) but .Reverse() in .NET solves that :D

Comment: @acidzombie: you could also order by find_in_set(…) desc

Comment: @knittl: Weird thing is, not only did it not do it but ASC and DESC dont get the same results in reverse order

Comment: order by FIELD(id, 4,5,1) can also be used

Answer (score 6):

Try a more explicit ordering:
`ORDER BY FIELD(id,4,5,1);`

Answer (score 0):

without an order by clause mysql is free to return the result in any order it wants.

you'd have to specify the ordering with `order by`

Comment: This is technically true but is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM Post WHERE flag='0' AND id = 4
UNION
SELECT * FROM Post WHERE flag='0' AND id = 5
UNION
SELECT * FROM Post WHERE flag='0' AND id = 1
```

It's horribly inefficient, but it won't require you to change your schema.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
select *
from Post 
where flag='0' and id = 4
UNION
select *
from Post 
where flag='0' and id = 5
UNION
select *
from Post 
where flag='0' and id = 1
```

Comment: sql operates on sets, and mysql is free to return those union query in any order (although usually it returns them without reordering)

Comment: This still does not address the question.