# MYSQL ORDER BY with an array of values in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, sql-order-by

I am working on a part of a search script where the submitted search string is parsed and each significant term placed into an array. The array is then looped through in the WHERE clause to search several columns in the MYSQL database. Here's a sample SQL code:

```
$sql = "SELECT title, question, tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5 FROM question WHERE ";

while(list($key,$val)=each($split_stemmed)){
          if($val<>" " and strlen($val) > 0){
          $sql .= 
           "(title LIKE '$val%' 
          OR question LIKE '$val%' 
          OR tag1 LIKE '$val%' 
          OR tag2 LIKE '$val%' 
          OR tag3 LIKE '$val%' 
          OR tag4 LIKE '$val%' 
          OR tag5 LIKE '$val%') OR";
          }
}
          $sql=substr($sql,0,(strLen($sql)-3));
          $sql .= "GROUP BY q_id ORDER BY 
           ((title LIKE '$val%') + 
            (question LIKE '$val%') + 
            (tag1 LIKE '$val%') + 
            (tag2 LIKE '$val') + 
            (tag3 LIKE '$val%') +
            (tag4 LIKE '$val%') +
            (tag5 LIKE '$val%')) desc, title asc";
```

The problem I am having is getting the ORDER BY to work correctly. The ORDER BY's purpose is to arrange the results of the query from the order of most hits on the search string to the least. My assumption is that I somehow need to loop through the array again in the ORDER BY clause, but am not sure of how to do this or if I am even correct in that assumption. Any helpers out there?

I know I can probably do this simpler using mysql full text search but the tables being used are InnoDB, so I dont think that is an option as of yet.

Comment: why do you have multiple tag columns?

Comment: Each question posted to the site can have multiple descriptive tags associated with it.

Comment: @Cbomb Look into normalizing your database. It will make your life 14% easier.

Comment: You don't `ORDER BY` a `LIKE` statement. You order by something specific, like a column in your table or your `SELECT` statement. If you need something else, use a `CASE` in the `ORDER BY`. (Your question should be based on just the SQL, and the PHP stuff should be removed; the question isn't about the PHP, but is an SQL issue instead. The PHP code just makes the question harder to read and answer.)

Comment: Please use full-text search, you're re-inventing the wheel here.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @Cbomb: Then you dont use multiple columns you use a many-to-many realtionship with three tables, `question`, `question_tag` and `tag`.

Comment: @prodigitalson:  I understand this idea in theory but why is it better to have three tables rather than just have all the data you need in the one table? With the tags in the same table I have twelve columns.

Comment: May this question might answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265512/mysql-in-array-order

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues to consider...

1) a NULL value in any of the columns tag1, tag2, tag3... in the ORDER BY expression is going to return a NULL for the entire expression. Consider:

```
SELECT 0 + NULL + 1 + 0
```

If all of those columns are defined as NOT NULL, then this isn't an issue. But more generally, you'd want to insulate from NULL values...

```
ORDER BY ( IFNULL(title    LIKE '$val%'),0) + 
           IFNULL(question LIKE '$val%'),0) + 
           IFNULL(tag1     LIKE '$val%'),0) + 
           IFNULL(tag2     LIKE '$val' ),0) +
```

-or alternatively-

```
ORDER BY ( IFNULL(title   ,'') LIKE '$val%') +
           IFNULL(question,'') LIKE '$val%') +
           IFNULL(tag1    ,'') LIKE '$val%') +
           IFNULL(tag2    ,'') LIKE '$val' ) + 
         )
```

(Seems like you're missing a `%` on tag2 based on the pattern, but it's entirely possible that omission is intentional

2) It's not at all clear why you need a `GROUP BY q_id` in your query.

---

I'd recommend you test by taking the expression in the ORDER BY clause, and copy it to your SELECT list, and run the query to see the values that it's returning.

In MySQL, if you add that expression to the SELECT list and give it an alias, you can reference the alias on the ORDER BY.

```
 SELECT expr AS match_count, ...
   FROM
  ORDER BY match_count DESC
```

Comment: Will test this as soon as I can. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you're looking for -- searching multiple columns for search terms and ordering by relevance -- is exactly what [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) was designed for.  If at all possible, you should use this as it will reduce your headaches in the long run.

If you absolutely must implement this way, then it's necessary to move the *LIKE* statements into the *SELECT* clause so that you can sum them.  Like this:

```
SUM (CASE WHEN title LIKE '$val%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN question LIKE '$val%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    + CASE WHEN tag1 LIKE '$val%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    ... etc
) AS relevance
```

Then to select only the matches, you could use `HAVING relevance > 0`.  And to order, you would simply use `ORDER BY relevance DESC` (since the *relevance* column as above will give you a count of the number of matching columns).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try to test this as soon as I can. As for full text search, I had read that as far as MYSQL is concerned, you can only use FTS with MYISAM tables although possibly FTS will soon also be available with InnoDB, and that MYISAM had such drawbacks that it was not worth using. Is this sound info in your opinion?

Comment: @Cbomb Honestly, I have no idea about the merits of MYISAM vs InnoDB.  Although, it looks like as of version 5.6 both are supported: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

Comment: Oh wow, yeah, MyISAM does not sound good... no transactions? no foreign key support???  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisam-storage-engine.html

Comment: Well I tried testing these possible solutions and nothing seems to want to work. Because of the many suggestions to go with Full Text Searching, I decided rather than trying to reinvent the  wheel I am abandoning this effort and am looking into using Sphinx as my search engine. Hopefully this will work well.